# Getting line length of geometry of parent feature as default value in child feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, length, qgsexpression

I have:

- a parent line-layer *'MyParentLineLayer'* (referenced layer) with a field `"parent_uuid"` (referenced field).
- a child geometryless-layer *'MyChildLayer'* (referencing layer) with a field `"parent_uuid_ref"` (referencing field).

I set up a relation between parent layer and child-layer as described before in project properties.

In parent-layer-properties - myRelation the checkbox "Force hide form on add feature" is checked.

I would like to get the line length of the parent-feature as a (editable) default-value in the child-features-form.

I tried:

```
length(
    geometry(
        get_feature('MyParentLineLayer', 'parent_uuid', current_value('parent_uuid_ref'))
        )
    )
```

as default-value-expression (widget type: text-editor, field type: double) but always got a `NULL`-value as line-length.

What is wrong with my code/settings?

Comment: What is the ```current value``` function, is a custom function?
I think it's just ```length(geometry(get_feature('MyParentLineLayer', 'parent_uuid', "parent_uuid_ref")))``` remember to put double quotes in ```parent_uuid_ref``` to get the current value of the field and not a constant string.

Answer (score 3):

**update**: answer below is only relevant when adding new features in *child* layer. Question has since been clarified to the child form that appears when adding feature to *parent* layer, and using a default value that depends on unsaved parent form values. Disregard answer below.

---

I believe `current_value()` is used more for widgets that are themselves configured to use a relation reference. Your line length widget in the child layer is just a simple widget with a default value so `current_value()` doesn't really work (that's my understanding).

Your expression should work if you use `"parent_uuid_ref"` instead of `current_value('parent_uuid_ref')`.

i.e.,

```
length(
    geometry(
        get_feature('MyParentLineLayer','parent_uuid',"parent_uuid_ref")
        )
    )
```

See below for example using above expression in default value field.

[image]

Comment: Tried this too before - but does not work in my (test-)-project. See small test-project at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ad79e58c3757805e690724da9d8d3d2a20220608054453/5362e5e8e14fe3da22738811496e623220220608054453/de7bce .Length-value shall be available in the form already on first digitzing of line - not only after it was saved (and "apply default value on update" shall not be checked as the value shall be editable)

Comment: @user191847 That's because you have a typo - your parent layer column is `parentuuid` and not `parent_uuid` - if you change the expression to match the parent layer column name it will work.

Comment: Excuse me. Thanks for your advice. Fixing the typo does not help. Tried it with QGIS 3.22.2 and 3.24.2. Line length is only shown in default-value-preview but not in the child form during digitizing a line. (Modified project at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d220214d44b6744d892b4b472fa2d16c20220608063935/9d6fc1123d5cd8c04650d388a95e793a20220608063935/eb59ba )

Comment: Ah, so you mean when you are digitising a feature in the parent layer (line layer), rather than creating a new record in your child layer (without geometry). Apologies, I didn't pick that up from your initial question. In that case, it does seem like the nested child form does not pick up UNSAVED parent attributes (or derived attributes) so I don't have an answer to your specific query, unfortunately. It may be worth raising it as an issue on github. I'll dig around a bit more to see what can be done

Comment: For now the best approach seems to be to add your feature in the line layer, save, then go back and edit the feature and THEN add a child feature. Alternatively, if you want to be able to edit the derived length value at the time of line feature creation, create a column for that in the line layer itself using a default value that you can edit, then reference that in your child feature (which, again, you can only create after saving the parent feature)

Comment: raised a feature request on github (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48915)